# data not showing in data base django postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-forms

i have to add data in database ,but after i click on sign up button i see my data in the python shell .but the data is not added in the database. i am using postgresql.
this is my code for register

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password1)
        user.save()
        return redirect('login.html')


    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')
```

my python shell shows this->

```
[14/Jul/2020 03:31:58] "GET /register?csrfmiddlewaretoken=znOO3WMBIwzO1Q8DhqgsX4Xj8pGNrBkY0p27uYSefVyGi6QaNaMjdmsBD2R5jVbt&userame=hello&email=hello%40hello.com&password1=hello&password2=hello HTTP/1.1" 200 1173
```

my imports in views.py ->

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
```

Comment: Your log says the form data was sent in a `GET` request.  Your `register()` function is looking for a `POST` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible because you are not validating your form
def register(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    email = request.POST['email']
    if form is_valid()
      password1 = request.POST['password1']
      password2 = request.POST['password2']

    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password1)
    user.save()
    return redirect('login.html')
```

try this one and you can add else part two fro showing error